# Preciso de ajuda para realizar uma iteração em uma lista de nomes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Enquanto treinava iteração, fiz a seguinte classe:

```
class MyRange:
  def __init__(self, start, end):
    self.value = start
    self.end = end

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.value >= self.end:
        raise StopIteration
    current = self.value
    self.value += 1
    return current

nums = MyRange(1, 10)
for num in nums:
    print(num)
```

que está funcionando perfeitamente, retornando:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

**Entretanto** tentei fazer o mesmo com uma lista de nomes, mas não funcionou:

```
class Nomes:
  def __init__(self, lista):
    self.lista = lista

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    indice_inicial = 0
    indice_final = len(self.lista)
    if indice_inicial >= indice_final:
        raise StopIteration
    indice_current = indice_inicial
    current = self.lista[indice_current]
    indice_inicial += 1
    return current

lista_de_nomes = Nomes(['marcos', 'felipe', 'lucas'])

for nome in lista_de_nomes:
    print(nome)
```

Nessa iteração, com nomes, por algum motivo, é criado um loop infinito repetindo sempre o primeiro nome, 'marcos':

```
marcos
marcos
marcos
marcos
marcos
marcos
...
```

Como consertar o código da classe nomes de forma que a iteração possa retornar:

```
marcos
felipe
lucas
```

Comment: Por que faz `indice_inicial = 0` toda vez que chama o `__next__`? Não adiantará de nada fazer `indice_inicial += 1` no final se na próxima execução voltará para 0.

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://ideone.com/s2r25Z ou https://ideone.com/SQ0d0X